# iunmap is not working inside my Vim script

Tags: key-bindings

I try to write a function to toggle my mappings in **Vim script**.

Here are the steps I have tested it:

1. I load my vim. (open a file)
2. Check my mapping in command mode with :imap and I can see mapping(etc. i ffff ...)
3. I press F6 to toggle the function
4. I got error message: **No such mapping**
5. I check my mapping in command mode with :imap again and I see the mapping(i ffff ...)
6. In command mode, I can use iunmpa  ffff to unmap the ffff
   **:iunmap  ffff**
7. The mapping is gone.(I can check with :imap)

Does anyone get any idea why **iunmap** is not working inside my Vim script?

Here is code

```
nnoremap <F6>    :call ToggleBracketGroup()<CR>
let g:bracketmap = 1
function! ToggleBracketGroup()
    if g:bracketmap == 1
        inoremap <buffer> ffff    print("cool")
        let g:bracketmap = 0
    else
        **iunmap <buffer> ffff**
        let g:bracketmap = 1
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with above code is there is **space** after ffff,

I have to remove the space after ffff and it works perfectly